# Using group_by function from dplyr, is there a way to group ranges of a single variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am looking at NBA statistics, particularly Points Scored Per Game and Salary. Currently summarizing them in R using `dplyr`'s group_by function. I am trying to group the PPG to look at salaries scored by players who have scored a specific range of Points per game. At the moment it just lists every single PPG value from my data, is there a way to turn it into a range. For example from 0-10 PPG, 10-20 PPG, 20-30 PPG and 30+.

Here is the line of code I have at the moment:

```
cps3 <- cps1 %>% group_by(PPG) %>%
       summarize(Mean_Salary = mean(Salary),
                 Min_Salary = min(Salary),
                 Max_Salary = max(Salary),
                 Number_of_Salaries = n())
```

`cps1` is just my data set.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a small sample of your data.

Comment: Take a look at the `cut` function. For example `cps1 %>% mutate(ppg_range = cut(ppg, seq(0, 100, 5), include.lowest=TRUE))`.

Comment: You could also the case_when function in a mutate  `cps1 %>% mutate(ppg_range = case_when(ppg > 0 & ppg =< 10 ~ "0-10 PPG", ppg > 10 & <= 20 ~ "10-20 PPG"))`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to created the new variable for groups and use it as a grouping variable.

```
cps1 %>% 
 mutate(PPG_tenths = floor(PPG/10)  ) %>%
 group_by(PPG_tenths ) %>%
 summarize(
   Mean_Salary = mean(Salary), 
   in_Salary = min(Salary), 
   Max_Salary = max(Salary), 
   Number_of_Salaries = n()
)
```

Comment: You could use a mutate with case_when to change all cases PPG_tenths > 3 to 3, if you want just 3 groups.